# Jquery function to check the opacity of an element fails if the value has been changed dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, function

I've been trying to solve this all night now, and I'm sure its something really obvious, so I'm hoping someone else will spot my mistake, because I just haven't got any more idea's.

In a very simplified version of a Jquery function I have the following;

**Jquery Function**

```
if(!$('#map-postcode').css("opacity") == 1){
    //Do some stuff first..
    //Then change the css opacity of the element   
    $('#map-postcode').animate({opacity: 0},2000, 'linear');
}else{
    //Then change the css opacity of the element   
    $('#map-postcode').animate({opacity: 1},2000, 'linear');
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your postcode" id="map-postcode"/>
<input type="button" value="Get Directions" id="place-directions"/>
```

FYI.  The function is called with the 'onclick' of the button

I know that the function call works, since the text input **does** disappear.  But it never comes back, and by adding alerts to both sides of the if/else, I know that the intial `if(!$('#map-postcode').css("opacity") == 1)` always returns true.

Can someone please explain why setting the opacity to 1 wouldn't then result in the functions *else* code block being executed.

And more importantly, is there a better way I can check for the opacity.

Just in case people are wondering, I don't want to use fadeToggle() etc. as I want the element to remain 'visible' (which is to say, the layout of the surrounding elements to **not** change), and I want the fade in/out effects (hence using the opacity animation).  Unless there are more elegant way's to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for `if(!$('#map-postcode').css("opacity") == 1)` to return true, regardless of the `opacity` value.  See http://jsfiddle.net/whv81hbs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to check `opacity` like that.  The problem is that `css('opacity')` returns a string value, which you're using with the not (`!`) operator:

```
!$('#map-postcode').css("opacity")
```

`!0` is equal to `true`, and `!1` is equal to `false`.

However, both `!'0'` and `!'1'` are equal to `false`.

Even if that were corrected, there may be a problem in your logic:

```
if opacity is not 1, then animate opacity to 0;
else animate opacity to 1.
```

If `opacity` is 0, `opacity` would be animated to 0.

If `opacity` is 1, `opacity` would be animated to 1.

Removing the not (`!`) operator makes the animations happen.

Comment: After reading your answer, then going back through my entire function (admittedly after just giving up and taking a 20 minute break), your completely right.  I've no idea why at any point I thought I needed the not operator.  I think maybe there were too many negatives involved in what I was trying to do, i.e. I was trying to check the value didn't not equal 0, which works out the same as does equal 1...  Stupid mistake to make really, but thanks for finding it, it really was driving me crazy!!

Comment: An extra pair of eyes can often make a difference.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine for me,

```
$("#place-directions").click(function(){
    if($('#map-postcode').css("opacity") == 1){
        //Do some stuff first..
        //Then change the css opacity of the element   
        $('#map-postcode').animate({opacity: 0},2000, 'linear');
    }
    else{
        //Then change the css opacity of the element   
        $('#map-postcode').animate({opacity: 1},2000, 'linear');
    };
});
```

I guess, the `!` operator that you are placing before the expression is creating the problem.

Alternatively, you can use the `toggleClass()` function onclick as following,

```
$("#place-directions").click(function(){
    $("#map-postcode").toggleClass("fadeIt");
});
```

and define in CSS as following,

```
.fadeIt{
    opacity: 0;
}
#map-postcode{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: in JavaScript, the ! is the not operator.  In Ricky's question, the if statement must satisfy the condition that the opacity of the element NOT be equal to one.  The answer you posted above has identical if and else statements, meaning that it isn't a test for anything.

Comment: Based on the fact that the OP expects something to happen, removing the not operator does seem to make sense.  +1

Comment: It does work now, and it was the not operator (!), as per answer given below (which I've marked as the answer).  Since both answers are correct, I marked the first one I read, which also explains where I was going wrong.  But thanks for the help!